# Custom checkbox image scale Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, checkbox, scale

I have made a checkbox in a drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/musican1"
            android:state_checked="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/musica"
            android:state_checked="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/musican1"/>
    </selector>
```

And I added it to my layout

```
<CheckBox
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:button="@drawable/checkmusic"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
```

The problem happens when the checkbox's size is less than the images' size. I can only see some part of the image, because it doesn't scales properly. I tried using scaleType, that is used in ImageView, but it doesn't work. Someone knows how could I scale it, so I see all the image in the size I fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll easily be able to achieve this with `CheckBox`. I would recommend switching to `ImageView` which supports `android:scaleType`.

Change your selector to use `selected` and not `checked`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musica" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musican1"/>
</selector>
```

Change your layout to use `ImageView` with `android:scaleType=centerInside`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:selected="true"
    android:src="@drawable/checkmusic"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

In code you would just set the click listener on the `ImageView` to toggle the selected state of the view.

```
    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    myImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Didn't work using selected, but you gave me the idea of using ImageView, so thanks!